# jQuery UI Disable All Submit Buttons on Entire Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

Thank you for any help in advance.

Please note I am using the jQuery UI to create / style buttons.

When a user clicks a submit button, I want to use jQuery to disable all submit buttons, on all forms, on the entire page.

Here is what I have so far, currently it only disables the button that was clicked, when I want it to disable all submit buttons on the page.

For the jQuery UI:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".button" )
.button()
});
</script>
```

For disabling buttons:

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$('.button').button().click(function() {
    $(this).button('disable');
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
    return false;
});
$('input:submit').button('enable');
});
</script>
```

The submit buttons / forms look like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="characters.php" method="post">
<input id="c_xp" class="text" type="text" value="150001" name="c_xp">
<input id="go" class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit" value="Go" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</form>
```

Comment: you want to disable them on click or what? they all should be disabled ?

Comment: They should be disabled onSubmit

Comment: take a look at the fiddle i provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, changing our disable code to:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('.button').button().click(function() {
    $('.button').button('disable');
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
    return false;
});
$('input:submit').button('enable');
});
</script>
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
       $("input[type='submit']).button('disable');
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
       return false;
    });
$('input:submit').button('enable');
});
</script>
```

You can do any of the statement.

```
$("input[type='submit']").button('disable');
OR 
$("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: This does not work, using this code even the clicked button does not disable.

Comment: to disable the clicked button you can do.. 
$(this).button('disable');  But you mentioned you want to disable all buttons.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but in my case I had to use button[type="submit"].  More info here: http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This code will make all buttons with a class `.button` disabled

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".button" ).button({ disabled: true });
});
```

and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/W7PEp/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that would disable all buttons.

```
function disableButtons() {
    $('input[type=button], input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('.button').button()(function() {
    $('input[type=button], input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work, using this code even the clicked button does not disable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```